# Use Sinhala unicode with Matlab

Tags: matlab, character

I have built a program to identfy braille characters from an image, there's no issue with program my program. It wroks correctly with English.

```
font=[font letter];
```

I take identified letters into above array,

```
fileID = fopen('text.text','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%s',font);
fclose(fileID);
winopen('text.text')
```

Then I print those letters into txt file using above code. 
Now I need to improve this to identify Sinhala braille, therefore I need to use Sinhala instead of English. Therefore I have to use Unicode. I don't know how to use this with MATLAB. Please help me. I have uploaded image of Sinhala unicodes here.

[Sinhala Unicode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oalSU.jpg)

Comment: WHAT? There is no question! where is your problem? you don't know how to write unicode into a file?

Comment: I want to print Sinhala text intead of English